# Waiting for ListView data

Tags: android, listview

I need your help in achieving following behaviour:

ActivityONE starts ActivityTWO, which holds ListView. Data for ListView is downloaded from the internet, when ActivityTWO starts. I want to display a ProgressBar in ActivityTWO while data is downloading and afterwards display ListView with downloaded data. In which points of ActivityTWO should I 'activate' the ListView with proper data? And how this 'postponing' should look like?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Two words: [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html).

Comment: But how do I notify the adapter, that there is any data to use?

Comment: No need to create the adapter until there's data. Once you have the data, fill the adapter and dismiss the progress dialog.

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() (this is how you notify the adapter)

Comment: Thank you guys for all these fast answers. My problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
public class YourActivity extends ListActivity{
private          ProgressDialog     progressBar;
private          Animation          rotation;
private          DownloadXmlTask    downloadXmlTask;
private          Boolean            Loading=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_main);        
    doDownload();              
}

private void doDownload()
{
        if ( isConnectedToInternet() ){
            downloadXmlTask=new DownloadXmlTask();  
            downloadXmlTask.execute();

        }
        else
                     Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this,"faild connection", 1).show();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if (Loading==true)
        stopLoadingAndDownloading();
}
//=====================
//New Class Starts Here
//=====================

class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
//your class

}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, 
        long id){
        //do something
    }

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Showing / Stopping progress dialog which is showing loading animation
 *  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
private void showLoading(){
    progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "", "");
    progressBar.setContentView(R.layout.YourLayout);
    progressBar.setCancelable(false);   
    //and another thing that need for progressBar
    Loading=true;
}

private void stopLoadingAndDownloading() {
    Loading=false;

    if(progressBar.isShowing())
        progressBar.dismiss();
    if (downloadXmlTask != null && downloadXmlTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED)
        downloadXmlTask.cancel(true);
}


public boolean isConnectedToInternet(){
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/*********************************************************
 * this class is a useful class that prevent from crashing
 *  when download of data take very long time
 *********************************************************/

private class DownloadXmlTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showLoading();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... esult) {
        //doing your download from internet
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //do something  
        setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter());        
        stopLoadingAndDownloading();
    }
}
}
```